# NanoHttpd save uploaded files

Tags: java, android, upload, webserver, nanohttpd

I have looked at many threads, but I can't find an answer to my question... 
So I could start the webserver on my device, and when I try to upload a file the browser says "upload successfully", but I couldn't find the file on my device and I don't know whether it is uploaded to the device. 
I have set all permissions and distinguish between `post` and `get` in my `serve` method.

I think I have to save the uploaded files from the parameter `Map<String, String>` files.
How could I do that? Is it the right way?

Here is my code snippet:

```
private class MyHTTPD extends NanoHTTPD {

    public MyHTTPD() throws IOException {
        super(PORT);
    }
    public Response serve(String uri, Method method, Map<String, String> headers, Map<String, String> parms, Map<String, String> files) {           
        if (method.equals(Method.GET)) {
            return get(uri, method, headers, parms, files);
        }
        return post(uri, method, headers, parms, files);
    }

    public Response get(String uri, Method method, Map<String, String> headers, Map<String, String> parms, Map<String, String> files) {
        String get = "<html><body><form name='up' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>"
                + "<input type='file' name='file' /><br /><input type='submit'name='submit' "
                + "value='Upload'/></form></body></html>";
        return new Response(get);
    }

    public Response post(String uri, Method method, Map<String, String> headers, Map<String, String> parms, Map<String, String> files) {
        String post = "<html><body>Upload successfull</body></html>";
        return new Response(post);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know, this is a very late response but I am posting the answer for future reference.

NanoHttpd automatically upload the file and saved in cache directory and return information (name,path etc) in files and params map. Write the following code in serve method.

```
File dst = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath() +"/"+ parameters.get("myfile"));
File src = new File(files.get("myfile"));
try {
      Utils.copy(src, dst);
}catch (Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();}
```

## Utils.copy

```
public static void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

    // Transfer bytes from in to out
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: Should we delete the temporary file? Or does NanoHttpd delete it at the end of the response?

Comment: NanoHttpd should delete cache files. If not system will. Don't worry about it.

Comment: Could you elaborate on where you find the "cache" directory? I don't have any `Environment` class in my classpath...

Comment: Sorry for confusing, this code is for Android system. Please change File dst = new File(savedFilePath) line for your system environment. And about cache, Nanohttpd use this.tmpdir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")) to create temp file, which will handle by JVM.